# Create new columns from aggregated categories

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe looks like:

```
    SK_ID_CURR  CREDIT_ACTIVE
0   215354  Closed
1   215354  Active
2   215354  Active
3   215354  Active
4   215354  Active
5   215354  Active
6   215354  Active
7   162297  Closed
8   162297  Closed
9   162297  Active
```

I would like to aggregate the number of active and closed credits for each id, and then make a new column for `Active_credits`, `Closed_credits` with the number of corresponding active and closed credits for each id.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), which avoids your suggested intermediary step:

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['SK_ID_CURR'], df['CREDIT_ACTIVE'])

print(res)

CREDIT_ACTIVE  Active  Closed
SK_ID_CURR                   
162297              1       2
215354              6       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `pd.DataFrame.groupby`

```
df1.groupby(['SK_ID_CURR','CREDIT_ACTIVE']).size()
```

Output:

```
SK_ID_CURR  CREDIT_ACTIVE
162297      Active           1
            Closed           2
215354      Active           6
            Closed           1
```

Comment: I think jpp's answer is better :)